# Multiple Renders EJS & Express

Tags: node.js

So, I have myself a code that makes multiple requests based on the used input.That's cool and everything working perfect. The loop is done and I get results. But I want to render status every time one request goes by. I have tried to do this by putting the render function into the loop but it didn't work well. It just rendered the first request status and broke afterwards.

```
lineReader.eachLine(./files/${finalName}, (line) => {

    const result = line.split(":");
    const options = {
        method: 'post',
        form:
        {
            'xxx': xxx,
            'xxx': xxx
        },
        json: false,
        url: "xxx",
        headers:
        {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Referer': 'xxx'
        }
    }

    const request = requests.defaults({jar: true});
    request(options, (err, res, body) => {
        console.log(`Making request`);

        if (!err) {

            if (body.includes("xxx")) {
                response.render('index', {
                    xxx: xxx
                });
            }
            else {
                response.render('index', {
                    xxx: xxx
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve], it's going to be very difficult to guess.

Comment: For a single request you can have only one response sent(render in this case) so you can't add the render inside a loop because the loop is being exposed for each request and it tries to render multiple times for a single request which is not legal.

Comment: So how could I solve this @jalil? Thanks for the response btw.